# Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints OAuth 2.0 Scopes

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to follow the following guide:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth

I've followed the steps and added the client id and the User parameter which when null I throw an OAuthRequestException exception.

When I deploy to Google and access the API using the API Explorer I get the expected unauthorised exception when accessing the API without OAuth. Great everything works so far!

It suggests to switch the OAuth 2.0 toggle. I do this and I get a message saying:

*** API does not declare any scopes. You can manually add scopes using the box below

the message also directs me to:
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html
to learn more about Scopes.

But there is very limited information about scopes on that suggested page. I'm new to OAuth and despite searching Google and StackOverflow 
I'm not sure what a scope is?
How do I declare on in the API?
When I manually add something to the API explorer prompt I get an error message saying it is an invalid_scope. So what is a valid scope?

Answer (score 5):

For authentication to work with cloud endpoints you will need to request this scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

The cloud endpoints library needs the user's email address to create a User entity from it.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js#adding-oath-authentication for reference.

Answer (score 1):

While @Scarygami's answer could be correct in 2013, now you should use this scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read
```

You can find warning about old `email` scope:

> Warning: This scope is deprecated. Google will no longer support this
>   scope after Sept. 1, 2014. For details, see Migrating to Google+
>   Sign-In.

More about scopes: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth

**EDIT:**

Looks like something has changed in the matter of supporting old `email` scope. Here's the actual statement.

> Note: This scope is deprecated; however, it will be maintained and
>   kept available for backward compatibility. For an explanation about
>   this change, see Migrating to Google+ Sign-In.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Scope documentation from google.

https://developers.google.com/drive/training/drive-apps/auth/scopes

Comment: Thanks the the pointer, but I'm not using a Google API and wanting to use Google scopes. My app doesn't need to access any personal data from a users Google Account. I'm writing my own API with Cloud Endpoints and I want to protect my API with Authentication so that only Authorised users can access the data served by my API.

Comment: did u happen to look at this URL. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth

Comment: having lots of trouble myself, retrofitting Endpoints into an existing app, with cookie based authentication. The problem is the bridge RestApiServlet (/_ah/api) -> SystemServiceServlet (/_ah/spi). Once a user hits it, that bridge remembers the session cookie so that any user (even no authenticated user) will appear to be authenticated as the first user!